# How to access Parse Dashboard on Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, heroku-api

I am trying to setup parse for a personal hobby project - I have decided to have it deployed on Heroku.

I followed the steps on this readme : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

I clicked on the `DEPLOY to HEROKU` button. Everything went fine. BUT I am NOT able to access the `Parse Dashboard`.

My configurations (its a test app - I will delete this & re-deploy, hence I am sharing the credentials) :

`APP_NAME` : `test1000000`

`SERVER_URL` : `http://test1000000.herokuapp.com/parse`

`APP_ID` : `test1000000`

`MATER_KEY` : `myMasterKey`

Is there something more I have to do?

When I try to access the below links on my browser, I see the following :

1. `http://test1000000.herokuapp.com/parse`

   => `Cannot GET /parse`
2. `http://test1000000.herokuapp.com/apps`

   => `Cannot GET /apps`
3. `http://test1000000.herokuapp.com/`

   => `I dream of being a website. Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!`

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you did. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard).
If you really want them in the same application, look at this part of docs

> If you want to run both Parse Server and Parse Dashboard on the same
>   server/port, you can run them both as express middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');

var allowInsecureHTTP = false

var api = new ParseServer({
    // Parse Server settings
});

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    // Parse Dashboard settings
}, allowInsecureHTTP);

var app = express();

// make the Parse Server available at /parse
app.use('/parse', api);

// make the Parse Dashboard available at /dashboard
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(4040);
```

**But** it's much more safe to have the dashboard as another app(it's free on heroku, because free plan is more than enough for it), or even deploy it on your localhost. Also I don't have the dashboard on my app, I just doing my stuff directly in mongolab dashboard.

Comment: this is helpful. Thanks @Andrew