# Parse server shows "Cannot GET /"

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to setup parse server on heroku but it seems it "Cannot Get /"

See here https://mvc-parse-server-clean.herokuapp.com/

I've set the `PARSE_SERVER_URL` as being `https://mvc-parse-server-clean.herokuapp.com/parse` in the Config vars. I've also set `PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PATH` as `/parse`
It should work, shouldn't it?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect on https://mvc-parse-server-clean.herokuapp.com? 
Parser server is working, and listening for incoming requests see:
https://mvc-parse-server-clean.herokuapp.com/parse

Comment: Hmm, my ultimate goal is to setup parse dashboard but I was getting the "cannot get /" error, or at least I thought it was an error. Isn't it?!

Comment: Ah okay. If you want to setup parse dashboard, then this error make sense. And you are right, it is an error and there is something wrong with your configuration (in that case take a look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198139/9147044)), or you did not install the dashboard because it's an [seperate app](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard).

Comment: No, I have yet to do anything regarding the dashboard, I first wanted to make the server work ... I'll start on the dashboard after that. But now that you're telling me it's running fine ... hmm ... I'll implement the dashboard and see where I can go from there. Thanks !

Comment: The dashboard is an UI to manage your app, not for creating one. Before you setup dashboard, you should be able to create and connect to your app like it is described [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#usage) use [your favorite sdk](http://parseplatform.org/#sdks) if you don't want to use express.js. If this is working, then your parse server is running fine and you can setup the dashboard.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, I would suggest joining the [parse community on gitter](https://gitter.im/ParsePlatform/Chat)

Comment: I don't need an expert. Basic knowledge to setup and configure's all I'd need from someone. :) But as you wish ^_^ Thanks for the link! I'll definitely make an account and ask around for more help there !